# Non-backed Key Set of Java Map

Tags: java, collections

Given the following Java `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

The following statement gives me a 'backed' set of the maps keys:

```
Set<Integer> keys = map.keySet();
```

but suppose I'd like a copy of the key set which I can manipulate without affecting the map. Is there a better/more correct way than

```
Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<Integer>();
for( Integer key : map.keySet() )
    keys.add( key );
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a slightly simpler way:

```
Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<Integer>(map.keySet());
```

...which just makes a copy in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<Integer>(map.keySet());
```

This will initialise a Set which contain exactly the same elements in the map's key set which is passed into the HashSet constructor.